# Find substring between specific characters

Tags: string, lua, substring, lua-patterns, nodemcu

I am unfamiliar with Lua language and a I would like your help. I am trying to receive some values through POST and the values is something like that:

```
pwd = password
ssid = ssid_name
```

---

```
swstat={string.find(payload,"pwd=")}
swstat1={string.find(payload,"ssid=")}
if swstat[2]~=nil then
    pass=string.sub(payload,swstat[2]+1,#payload)
    ssid=string.sub(payload,swstat1[2]+1,#payload)
    print("Password: "..pass)
    print("SSID: "..ssid)
end
```

The actual result of the above code is ( am sending through a web browser the ssid=htc and password=fr):

```
Password: fr
SSID: htc&pwd=fr
```

I would like to have in a string the password only and in another string the ssid. 
So my idea is to search into string with the following logic:
ssid = find in string the sub string which is between "ssid=" and ("&" or end of string)
pwd = find in string the sub string which is between "pwd=" and ("&" or end of string)

Comment: `pass = payload:match'%f[%C]pwd=(%C+)'`, `ssid = payload:match'%f[%C]ssid=(%C+)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `payload` is a valid query string format, you can store related information inside a table:

```
local tData = {}
for sParam, sValue in payload:gmatch "([^=&]+)=([^=&]+)" do
    tData[sParam:lower()] = sValue
end
```

Now, you'll have the information inside the `tData` table:

```
tData.pwd     -- will have fr
tData.ssid    -- will have htc
```