# Extract a substring in Lua

Tags: lua, substring, extract

I would to extract ssid and password and save them in two variables from my payload. My payload is:
ssid=ssid&password=password&confirm=confirm
The language is LUA.
Thanks who helps me.

Comment: any ideas? this isn't a coding service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find substring between specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232873/find-substring-between-specific-characters)

Answer (score 3):

Use [string.match](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-string.match) with a suitable [string pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1).
The pattern should capture both ssid and password.